# Best design approach for storing documents

Tags: sharepoint

We have a sharepoint website and as part of functional process across the website where there are lot of documents been uploaded. Currently they are been stored into database which results in very bulky table in terms of size. My initial approach was to utilize sharepoint to store the documents into file library. Does anybody think database is the wiser options and why or any other approach which is performant and better to store confidential files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a database for storing documents is not a recommended approach, not only it will have large size but will be hard when it comes to maintenance and performance.

If you have a SharePoint server, why not go with a library or multiple libraries to store documents. You will get the below advantages when using SharePoint.

1.Permission management : you can set up access to documents and choose who access what.

2.Search : if there is a search service running you can search through your libraries.

3.OWA : office web apps can be used to open documents on the browser.

4.Audits : You can enable audit logs to see who does what.

Remember, SharePoint is a CMS and there are other options like MMS etc, but it stores the documents in a database too, its designed well so you dont have to worry much about it. If you go with your custom solution you will have to do a lot of custom development and testing.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Completely in line with your view. Most of the native  file library tools never risk to keep the file on the file explore, it mostly goes it their designed database. SP again maintain's its own database but my primary argument was to see does it make any sense to build something which is already there, tried and tested and struggle to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I never recommend saving files in the database.  The easiest approach is to store them on the server in a directory and only save the file names in the database.  This makes it easy to show them via a URL in a browser as well. Create a table with a column for the OriginalFileName and one for the ActualFileName.  When i save a file to the server after its uploaded i usually change the name so you never have complications with duplicate file names.  I use a GUID as the actual file name when its saved and save the original file name in the database along with the actual so you can get both back.